# Angularjs not rendering page after updating for touch event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Initially I was having code as below. and it's working fine.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
```

now I need to integrate touch events into my application so I modified this as, and I added angular-touch.js library script and updated code as

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngTouch']);
```

but after adding this Its not rendering page and not giving any error. I am using AngularJS v1.1.5 as base library and AngularJS v1.2.0rc1 for touch. In y application I am using ng-repeat images functionality and search

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Without more info on our html markup and/or controller code it will be quite hard to help you. But anyway I have assembled a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/djM6SMcdLh2x78h6q0K9?p=preview) where the touch is working.

```
// HTML markup
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Controller">
  <button ng-click="touch()">Touch</button>
</body>

//App, Controller code
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch']);
app.controller('Controller', ['$scope',
  function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.touch = function() {
      alert('touch');
    }
  }]);
```

Be careful for it to work you need to either browse the site with a touch capable device or if you are using chrome [emulate the touch events](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#emulate-touch-events) from the developer tools settings.

Comment: Thanks for Reply Nicolas but when I place code like var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch']); this it doesnt render app ahead. "chrome emulate the touch events from the developer tools settings." is helpful. Thanks